# Перевести столбец в строку python

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть проблема. Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы вытащить столбец из некой таблицы и записать его длину `len()`. Но мой код выдает его в столбец, из-за чего `len()` считает каждый элемент столбца отдельно, а не их общее количество

```
for col in water:
    el = list(col.split()[2])
```

water.txt:

```
     HETATM    1  H   HOH A   1      27.265  36.739  58.126
     HETATM    2  H   HOH A   1      27.109  35.124  57.944                          
     HETATM    3  O   HOH A   1      27.486  35.958  57.542
...
     HETATM 9999  O   HOH A3333      30.490  83.899  10.929
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а так не устраивает?

```
water = [
    "HETATM    1  H   HOH A   1      27.265  36.739  58.126",
    "HETATM    2  H   HOH A   1      27.109  35.124  57.944",
    "HETATM    3  O   HOH A   1      27.486  35.958  57.542",
]

column = [line.split()[6] for line in water]

print(column)
```

на выходе список из значений в 6 столбце (для примера)

или вам что-то иное нужно?

вот код из файла:

```
with open('d:\\watercube.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    column = [line.split()[6] for line in lines if len(line.split()) > 6]
    print(column)
```

Comment: К сожалению, да! water.txt файл имеет 9999 строк, мне нужно достать некоторые столбцы. Чтобы потом обработать их и перезаписать.

Comment: тогда лучше задание уточнить, а то не очень понятно :(

Comment: Моя вина, прошу прощения

Comment: Кажется, я был не прав. Ваш вариант, похоже, близок к тому, что мне нужно, но т.к. у меня около 10к строк мне нужно сделать сплит каждой из них.`water = water.readlines()` раньше работал, но теперь сплитит только первую колонку. И не видит столбцов дальше `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: вы куда нибудь выложите сам файл чтобы с ним можно было поработать и тогда будет понятно в чем ошибка

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/rrEWq 
Тем не менее моем в первоначальном варианте строки разделялись как нужно

Comment: @knowname, я проверил работу кода - ошибка выдавалась, потому что иногда строка не разбивалась на 6 кусков и поэтому был выход за диапазон (проверьте свой файл - вы одинаково выдаете все строки или нет). Поэтому я добавил выборку только из тех строк, которые можно разбить на 6 частей. И еще - обращение к [6] я взял просто для демонстрации, какой именно столбец нужен вам смотрите сами

Comment: большое спасибо! Это именно то, что мне было нужно!